# Is there a central site for accessing physics data for research?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model, data

What I'm looking for is a central website where you can search for, say, "quantum entanglement experimental results" and it would give you links to various other sites. Similarly if you wanted "radio telescope observations" it would return a list of links to radio telescope observations from other sites.

I am aware that things like http://adswww.harvard.edu/ exist, but I'm more hoping for one central research resource.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in particle physics you might find the [PDG Data group site](http://pdg.lbl.gov/) useful. Published results can be found there in tables and numbers.